# db_select condition with subquery causes PDOexception

Tags: 7, database

I want to build a relative simple select query with a subquery in its condition. What I want to achieve is to get the list of users updated after a given timestamp.

The working SQL-Query which I want to build as dynamic query is:

```
SELECT uid 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `vid` > (
  SELECT vid 
  FROM `user_revision` 
  WHERE `timestamp` > 1379494886 
  ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC 
  LIMIT 1
);
```

I've written the following code to build above query with Drupal's Database API:

```
$subquery = db_select('user_revision', 'ur')
  ->fields('ur', array('vid'))
  ->where('ur.timestamp > 1379494886')
  ->orderBy('ur.timestamp', 'ASC')
  ->range(0, 1);

$query = db_select('users', 'u')
  ->fields('u', array('uid'))
  ->condition('u.vid', $subquery, '>');

$result = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();
```

But, I'm getting the following PDOexception error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in
>       your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>       syntax to use near 'SELECT ur.vid AS vid FROM user_revision ur WHERE (ur.timestamp >
>       137949488' at line 1: SELECT u.uid AS uid FROM {users} u WHERE (u.vid > SELECT ur.vid AS vid
>       FROM {user_revision} ur WHERE (ur.timestamp > 1379494886) ORDER BY ur.timestamp ASC LIMIT 1
>       OFFSET 0) ; Array ( ) in MYMODULE_page_callback() (line 22 of
>       /path/to/the/module/includes/page_callback_file.inc).

What am I doing wrong building the subquery?

Comment: [SelectQuery::condition()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Acondition/7) doesn't mention that it supports sub queries for the value parameter (in fact it only mentions scalars and array). That's probably the problem

Comment: Yes, I would not expect subqueries to be supported by the PDO, from my experience of how queries are built. You will need to use db_query instead of db_select.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I was sure that I did read about subqueries could be used in db_select.

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/310086 On this page, under **Subselects** section, I've read about that, but seemingly it doesn't work well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @Clive's comment, I checked the documentation about the subqueries on https://drupal.org/node/310086 and I noticed the note about:

> Note: Currently it is only possible to use subselect conditions with the IN operator because with the other operators the sub-query is not wrapped in parentheses and so results in a syntax error. See #1267508: Subselects don't work in DBTNG conditions, except when used as value for IN.

I've changed my code to use `IN` instead of `>` and it worked like a charm. Here's the working code for future reference if someone falls into the same situation:

```
$subquery = db_select('user_revision', 'ur')
  ->fields('ur', array('vid'))
  ->where('ur.timestamp > 1379494886')
  ->orderBy('ur.timestamp', 'ASC');

$query = db_select('users', 'u')
  ->fields('u', array('uid', 'vid'))
  ->condition('u.vid', $subquery, 'IN');

$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Not sure how relevant this is, but I noticed you remove the `LIMIT` from the subquery. Interestingly, the [Restrictions on Subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html) would've caused that to fail even if PDO had got the syntax right. Not something I've come across before

Comment: I removed the `LIMIT` to be able to use `IN` instead of `>`, since I needed all values returned by the subquery, not only the smallest one.

Comment: Ok, it was not directly relevant. To test it I just added the `LIMIT` back and got another error this time: `PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1235 This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery':...`

Answer (score -1):

You could separate your subquery into another query to return just the value, see below:

```
$vid = db_select('user_revision', 'ur')
  ->fields('ur', array('vid'))
  ->where('ur.timestamp > 1379494886')
  ->orderBy('ur.timestamp', 'ASC')
  ->range(0, 1)
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();

$query = db_select('users', 'u')
  ->fields('u', array('uid'))
  ->condition('u.vid', $vid, '>');

$result = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();
```

Comment: This way is no better than the solution I posted. It is almost the same, but using 2 queries instead of just one, so it is worse for performance. I see no point why did you post almost the same answer, splitting it into two queries.