# convert 2 select in db_select

Tags: database

I have this query in SQL

```
select * 
from node n, node_collection_data nc
where n.nid = nc.nc_child_nid
and 
nc.nc_parent_nid = (select nc_parent_nid
from node_collection_data
where nc_child_nid=17)
```

This is what I got so far:

```
 $query -> join('node_collection_data', 'nc', 'n.nid =
 nc.nc_child_nid'); $query->condition('type', $node->type)
       ->condition('status', 1)
       ->condition('n.nid', $node->nid, '!=')
       ->condition(db_or()
       ->condition('n.language', array($language->language, LANGUAGE_NONE), 'IN')
         ->condition('n.language', $node->language, '=')
       )
       // get nc_child_id
       //->join('node_collection_' . $sort, $sort, 'n.nid = ' . $sort . '.nc_child_id')
       ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
       ->fields('nc',array('nc_parent_nid')) // select nc_parent_id
```

I am trying to convert the last part.

```
nc.nc_parent_nid = (select nc_parent_nid from node_collection_data where nc_child_nid = 17)
```

How can I convert it to `db_select()`?

Comment: You need to search for db_select using subquery.

Comment: May be this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90428/db-select-condition-with-subquery-causes-pdoexception can help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for db_select using subquery.

Look the below links to get some idea.

[Using db_select with subqueries](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91679/using-db-select-with-subqueries)

[db_select condition with subquery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90428/db-select-condition-with-subquery-causes-pdoexception)

Comment: I trust you have good reasons to post those links as an answer here. But I suggest you extend your answer with some relevant "quotes" from those 2 links. Not because "I" ask so, but it'll avoid your answer will (pretty sure) gets classified as "low quality answer" (and then deleted?) and/or gets downvoted. Just trying to help, OK?

Answer (score 0):

Put your subquery in a variable like

```
$subquery = "(select nc_parent_nid from node_collection_data where nc_child_nid = 17)";
```

And then use it with addExpression function in your main query

```
$query->addExpression($subquery, 'sub_query');
```

Use the following debug function to check your query

```
dpm((string) $query);
dpm($query->arguments());
```